# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm very new to unit Testing in vue js. I just went through this website to learn unit testing "https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-single-file-components-with-mocha-webpack". while I'm practicing the examples in "mocha-webpack" I got this Error

```
WEBPACK  Failed to compile with 1 error(s)
Error in ./src/Counter.vue
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
at /opt/htdocs/guru/unitTest_prct/node_modules/prettier/index.js:32893:5
at /opt/htdocs/guru/unitTest_prct/node_modules/prettier/index.js:32913:4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mdbvue@4.2.0 test: `mocha-webpack --webpack-config  webpack.config.js --require test/setup.js test/**/*.spec.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mdbvue@4.2.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely     additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-09-06T10_28_47_073Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this error. This is my Counter.vue file

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div>
     {{ count }}
     <button @click="increment">Increment</button>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
       return {
         count: 0
       }
    },
   methods: {
      increment () {
        this.count++;
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

Here is my Counter.spec.js File

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Counter from '../src/docs/Counter.vue'
describe('Counter.vue', () => {
  it('increments count when button is clicked', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Counter)
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.find('div').text()).toMatch('1')
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you post your Counter.vue file?

Comment: @ yuriy636 I have updated my counter.vue file

Comment: can we see your imports, please?

Comment: @P3trur0 here I add my Counter.spec.js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem related with version **1.14.1** of `prettier`, that is a NPM package used in your scenario.

Indeed, looking at their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5018) the issue is reported. At the moment there is a possible workaround: basically, it is to comment out line 32893 of `prettier/index.js`.

In your environment you can find the file here: `/opt/htdocs/guru/unitTest_prct/node_modules/`.

Comment: Good! Of course, please mind that it is a workaround not suitable in production.

Comment: but I have a doubt if the version is my problem means now I have updated my version to 1.14.1 to 1.14.2 but still I am facing this issue.why?

Comment: the bug looks still open on GitHub; 1.14.1 is the version where it was introduced. it will be fixed in the future I suppose.

Comment: thx, had the same problem, and you saved my day. Any idea how to do it in a less 'hackish' way?

Comment: hi @themathmagician, glad it helped. AFAIK, the one suggested here is the current workaround to deal with the problem. Alternatively you could evaluate to downgrade the version of this NPM dependency.

Comment: I am using `sed -i.bak  '32893s/^../\/\//' node_modules/prettier/index.js` to comment out that line when we make a new setup - but would appreciate guidance how to downgrade the offending prettify version? do you mean to downgrade the vue test utils?

Comment: @themathmagician yes, I meant so. You should check which version of vue-test-utils depends on a NPM module using prettifier 1.14.1 version and replace it accordingly. However, IMHO, since this bug should be fixed in future versions, I'd stay with the workaround for a while, before of considering the downgrade.

Answer (score 7):

I've looked at [the issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/936) linked [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204427/3718498).

I have `--require test/setup.js` in the test script. Here's how it looks like:

```
require('jsdom-global')();
window.Date = Date;
```

It solved the problem. Try it out!